# What do you call the generalisation of the direct image?

Tags: set-theory, online-resources, alternative-set-theories

## Informal Description

Let me start with an example. Let $X$ be the set $\{a, b, c, d, e\}$ and $E$ be the set $\{a, b, c\}$. Let $f$ be a function with domain $X$.
Then the mapping that sends $E$ to $\{f(a), f(b), f(c) \}$ is called the direct image of $E$ under $f$, denoted by $f_*(E)$.

Now, let $W$ be the set $\{\{a, b\}, \{c\}\}$. What do you call the mapping that sends $W$ to $\{\{f(a), f(b)\}, \{f(c)\}\}$ ?

Informally, this mapping replaces every element of $X$ *"inside"* $W$ with its image under $f$.

## Slightly More Formal Description

Let us assume the [ZFA-axiomatisation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ZFA#:%7E:text=ZFA%20is%20a%20variant%20of,made%20up%20of%20other%20elements.) of Set Theory, a variant of ZF that allows non-set objects called atoms. Let $A$ be a set of atoms.

Define $P^0(A)$ = A.

And for all $n \in \mathbb{N} \colon$ define $P^n(A)= \mathscr{P}(P^{n-1}(A)) \cup A $ ,

where $\mathscr{P}(-)$ denotes the powerset of a set.

And define $P^{\infty}(A)$ as $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} P^{n}(A)$

Let $X$ be a set of atoms. Let $f$ be a function with domain $X$. We could then inductively define a function $f_{**}$ such that $dom(f_{**}) = P^{\infty}(X) \backslash X$ , and $f_{**}$ has the property that for all $Z \in dom(f_{**}) \colon f_{**}(Z) = \{f_{**}(T) | T \in Z \backslash X \} \cup \{f(x) | x \in Z \cap X \}$.

### Examples

- Let $X = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$ be a set of atoms. Then $\{a, \{b\}\} \in P^{\infty}(X) \backslash X$ and $f_{**}(\{a, \{b\}\}) = \{f(a), \{f(b)\}\}$
- Let $X = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$ be a set of atoms. Then $\{\{ \{c \} \}\} \in P^{\infty}(X) \backslash X$ and $f_{**}(\{\{\{c \} \}\}) = \{\{\{f(c) \} \}\}$

So $f_{**}$ can, in a sense, be thought of as a generalisation of the direct image. My quesiton is, what do you call this concept? And can you point me towards any resources regarding it? I would prefer if the resource makes use of the ZFA-axiomatisation, but I would also accept any other resource.

Comment: Sounds similar to a [functor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor) but I don't believe it is the same thing.

Comment: This concept shows up in functional programming as variants of the *map* functional, which is often thought of in terms of [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming). This ties up with the categorical notion of [monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad).

Comment: @RobArthan After a little bit of Googling, I can see how the concept of the direct image is related to the map functional. Can you please explain how the generalisation of the direct image shows up as a variant of the map functional?

Comment: From the functional programming point of view, data types like sets, lists, trees etc. each have their own map functional. In your ZFA world, you can view any set as standing for a data type (representing the type of all things that can be obtained by substituting sets for the atoms in the sets) and you are putting together all the map functions for those data types. I am sorry if this is a bit vague: I was just trying to provide you with some pointers to related concepts.

Comment: There is a notation, apparently due to Russell and Whitehead, that uses apostrophes to signify the level at which a function operates. $f ` x$ means $f (x)$ in the usual sense, $f `` x$ is the set $\{ f ` y : y \in x \}$, $f ``` x$ is the set $\{ f `` y : y \in x \}$, and so on. In modern language this is iteration of the powerset functor.

Comment: @ZhenLin Technically speaking, is it actually the iteration of the powerset functor? Because we note that I also union the set of atoms at each of my iterations

Comment: @Yes Why are you stopping at the $ω$ stage? And why do you remove $X$ itself from the domain.$$$$
A more "natural" definition will be $P_0=X$, for $α$ an ordinal, $P_{α+1}=P_{α}∪\mathcal{P}P_{α}$, for $β$ limit ordinal, $P_{β}=\bigcup_{γ∈β}P_{γ}$ and lastly $P_∞=\bigcup_{δ∈Ord}P_{δ}$.$$$$
In this construction we have $P_{ω}=P^{∞}$, but, unlike your $P^{∞}$ - my $P_{∞}$ is the class of all sets that can be built from only $A$(and other sets). [1/2]

Comment: If you are using that construction the extension you described is used a lot for bijections $f:A→A$ in [permutation models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_model), and as far as I know it doesn't have a name, but simply saying "the automorphism that induced from $f$" is clear enough for people to understand what you meant (in permutation models we look at the set of all permutations $π:A→A$, and extend all of of those bijections to $P_∞$). When $f$ is not a bijection the result function is not automorphism tho [2/2]

Comment: @ℋolo Yes what are describing is very close to what I am describing. You're right that we don't need to stop at the ω-stage.

Comment: The reason why I'm removing $X$ from the domain is so that it has the property:
 for all $Z \in dom(f_{**}) \colon f_{**}(Z) = \{f_{**}(T) | T \in Z \backslash X \} \cup \{f(x) | x \in Z \cap X \}$